# how to read the parameters from excel or other type of file and run the rest API request one by one using groovy script

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

**I have soap ui project structure like below :**
TestSuite
 TestCase
  TestStep
   Rest request (json)

**I would like to get data from file (e.g) like below :**

```
title description type name date surname

myTitle myDescription 111111 Maria 2017-01-01 Romano

myTitle myDescription1 222222 John 2017-01-02 Soprano

myTitle2 myDescription2 333333 Robert 2017-01-03 Hermano
```

(any file : xls, csv, json) and run my rest request using data from file for each row in file.

```
{

 "action":"save",
   "value" : {  

      "title":"${title}",
      "description":"${description}",
      "type":${type},
      "name":"${name}",
      "date":${date},
      "surname": "${surname}",
}

}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you using ReadyAPI?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to get request content , parse it, change value, build request again , set request and send it.

There is lot of reference on web on how to parse excel with groovy like [this](https://erdyes.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/read-from-excel-file-with-groovy/) . Look around, you may find more ways . So , 
If you have values in these groovy variables after parsing excel,

```
title
description
type name 
date 
urname
```

then for a test case, you can do like below. I'll explain for one variable `title` , you can do others same way. Put this in a groovy test step of a test case and run

```
 import groovy.json.*

 //get the test step
   getAllHttpSteps=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepsOfType(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep)
    for (step in getAllHttpSteps){

    //get request content
    RawRequest = step.testRequest.getRequestContent()

    //Parse Json request content
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def parsed_MessageBody = slurper.parseText(RawRequest)

      //get the node you want to change and its new node value
       def TitleKey= value.title   //from your json 

       //change desired json node in request
    def node= "parsed_MessageBody"+"."+TitleKey
    Eval.me('parsed_MessageBody', parsed_MessageBody, "$node = '$title'")


         //Build Json request again with new values
    def builder = new JsonBuilder(parsed_MessageBody)
    def json = builder.toPrettyString()
    json = groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(json)


      //set new request content to request
    step.testRequest.setRequestContent(json)

    //Run new request
    step.run(testRunner,testRunner.getRunContext())

    }
```